# How to use @RefreshScope with @EnableBinding-annotated classes?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

`@EnableBinding` turns class into `@Configuration`, and it's [documented](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_refresh_scope) that:

> @RefreshScope works (technically) on an @Configuration class, but it might lead to surprising behaviour: e.g. it does not mean that all the @Beans defined in that class are themselves @RefreshScope. Specifically, anything that depends on those beans cannot rely on them being updated when a refresh is initiated, unless it is itself in @RefreshScope (in which it will be rebuilt on a refresh and its dependencies re-injected, at which point they will be re-initialized from the refreshed @Configuration).

So just a practical question: is there a way still to update some Receiver class annotated with `@EnableBinding`? I guess it would not be handled by the framework, and should be implemented with a custom `@EventListener`

Answer (score 0):

For our simplest examples, we use the `@Configuration` classes where `@EnableBinding` is declared as the business logic beans themselves, which is made possible by the fact that `@EnableBinding` is a `@Configuration` and therefore a `@Component`. Since you don't need `@EnableBinding` on the Receiver bean itself, for example, I would separate the logic into a bean annotated with `@RefreshScope`. `@EnableBinding` itself is not subject to refresh, although the channels would be unbound/rebound on start/stop.